# How to Connect FCM (Female) to NPT (Female)?

Tags: water, kitchens, sink, waterproofing, valve

I am working on a DIY Home Improvement Project in the kitchen, and I want to connect an Ice Maker Water Line with a **1/4 inch FCM (Female Compression)** connector to a Solenoid Valve with a **1/4 inch NPT (Female)** connector.

[image: FCM to NPT]

Is there an existing adapter that could connect these two female ports?

How could I best connect these to ensure that there are no leaks?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? https://www.amazon.com/Anderson-Metals-Fitting-Connector-Compression/dp/B0044FB02Y

Comment: @Huesmann Your link is considered an ad by at least my adblocker so doesn't work for me. Also, all the fittings I've seen from that brand contain lead and are not allowed for potable water use in the US at least.

Comment: You may also wish to verify with the solenoid valve maker that it is suitable for potable water use.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0044FB02Y let's see if SE thinks this is an ad too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, adapters between compression thread and pipe thread exist. I had to find one to connect to a widget which had been tapped for compression thread for no reason I can comprehend... In the US, your local hardware store probably has a rack of thread adapters stuck away in a back corner; ask them for help.

Comment: Just a note that the compression thread is not tapered, and the seal is to the flat rim of the male end (no teflon tape or sealant), while the NPT end will seal by metal/metal thread contact, and will need teflon tape or food-safe sealant.

Comment: @keshlam Is NPT the standard pipe thread sold at hardware stores? I checked the stores, but none of them explicitly mentioned NPT.

Comment: American National Pipe Thread standard, often shortened to NPT.  (Warning: Edge of continent; no consistent reality beyond this point...) Websearch will find details.